# Exfat Drive Appears as HPFS/NTFS

Tags: filesystems, fuse

I have a thumb drive which is formatted to exfat and mounted to debian squeeze with exfat-fuse. When I use the command `sudo fdisk -l` it would give

```
Device Boot         Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         976     7833599    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

So what is the reason it shows as NTFS but not exfat.

Answer (score 0):

If its formated correctly in exFat then it should show exFat filesystem when you do fdisk. You can try mounting it on a windows file system and check what it shows. I'm not sure if windows xp will but i think anything above xp should show the disk as exFat.